# Django dropdown showing model Fields

Tags: django, django-models

I want to display a dropdown that contains the string values of the Field names in one of my models.

**models.py** :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    meat = models.CharField()
    veggies = models.CharField()
    fish = models.CharField()
```

**forms.py**:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['foodTypes']
```

The dropdown should then show

```
meat
veggies
fish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyForm(Form):
    food_types = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=[])

    class Meta:
        fields = ['food_types']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['food_types'].choices = [x.name for x in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if condition]
```

The condition may vary. Maybe it will be `if isinstance(x, fields.CharField)`

Comment: did you mean ```x.name for x in blah```?

Comment: Great. My setup has changed a bit between my original post and your answer. Can you please check this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60723734/django-multiple-dropdowns-showing-model-objects